# What would be the best data structure to use? java

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a GUI where people can enter data and I'm not sure what the best way to store the data would be. This is how I would visualize the data:

```
Cats: Cheetah, lion, puma
Dogs: husky, lab
```

The user could add a type of animal, like a fox, and then add types of foxes. They could also add new types of cats and dogs to the existing lists of them. What would be the best data-structure to use to store this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `HashMap<String, Set<String>>`.

Example:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> animals = new HashMap<>();

// To add a new category of animal
animals.put("Cat", new HashSet<>());
animals.put("Dog", new HashSet<>());

// To add a new animal to an existing category
animals.get("Cat").add("Puma");
animals.get("Cat").add("Tiger");
animals.get("Dog").add("Labrador");

// prints {Cat=[Tiger, Puma], Dog=[Labrador]}
System.out.println(animals);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Map<Family,Set<Species>>`

For concrete classes, I might use `TreeMap` and `TreeSet`, making sure that my `Family` and `Species` types implement comparable (or these types could be replaced by `String`). These types are sorted, so iterating over them would display data in a sensible order.

Comment: Why not have Set<Species> wrapped in a class Members

Comment: @AmirAfghani What API would `Members` class provide that wouldn't fit just as well on `Family`? Unless it implements `Collection`, defining a non-standard collection type would inhibit interoperability with `Collection`-oriented APIs. In the absence of any compelling reason to wrap it, I wouldn't do it as a matter of course.

Comment: Maybe family is not the correct abstraction then.  Maybe Genus, or Category, or something

Comment: I agree @erickson that one should not do it as a matter of course.  I'm not familiar enough with the data model to make a strong recommendation.  If anything, I would at least use a standard library like Guava for something like what you've written...

Comment: @AmirAfghani Yes, genus would probably be better.

Comment: I'd rather have `Family` having a member map/set of `Species` instead.  That seems to be a more proper object model.

Comment: @AdrianShum Yep, that's what I suggested on Amir's answer.

Comment: @erickson Yup, I saw that after I wrote this comment (and I have upvoted your comment  :P )

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> container
```

Where the first String refers to the animal type name and the arraylist holds animal names under that type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guava's [MultiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) to manage something like:

```
Map<Key, CollectionOfValues>
```

I would think about the data model a bit more and see if you can create a wrapper class for the members of each group.  This will make the code more readable in the long run.  Perhaps:

```
Map<Genus, Members>
```

Comment: Right, maybe rather than "data structure", you have a `Genus` with `members:Set<Species>` property.